# Can we incorporate Zephyr Enterprise Gadgets into our Atlassian Jira Dashboard, similar to how it's done with their Scale (Cloud) version?

Tags: testing, project-management, testcase, jira-zephyr

Certainly, we're interested in the possibility of integrating Zephyr Enterprise Gadgets into our Atlassian Jira Dashboard. We want to explore if this can be accomplished in a manner how it is executed with their Scale (Cloud) version. The Jira Dashboard plays a pivotal role in streamlining our project management processes, and having access to these gadgets could enhance our ability to track and manage our projects effectively.

By incorporating Zephyr Enterprise Gadgets, we aim to achieve a more comprehensive overview of our projects, allowing us to make informed decisions and ensure efficient project execution. It's crucial for us to determine if such an integration is feasible and how it aligns with our project management needs. In doing so, we hope to optimize our use of Jira and leverage its capabilities to the fullest extent.

Certainly, we're interested in the possibility of integrating Zephyr Enterprise Gadgets into our Atlassian Jira Dashboard. We want to explore if this can be accomplished in a manner akin to how it is executed with their Scale (Cloud) version. The Jira Dashboard plays a pivotal role in streamlining our project management processes, and having access to these gadgets could enhance our ability to track and manage our projects effectively.

By incorporating Zephyr Enterprise Gadgets, we aim to achieve a more comprehensive overview of our projects, allowing us to make informed decisions and ensure efficient project execution. It's crucial for us to determine if such an integration is feasible and how it aligns with our project management needs. In doing so, we hope to optimize our use of Jira and leverage its capabilities to the fullest extent.